# Get Dropbox shareable link metadata

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox

I have been assigned a project where I need to get the following dropbox metadata from a shareable link. I need to get the path and also the name of the folder/file that was shared.

For example here is a link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7tlk1onrl2i7yjk/AABSsM8fWJ9RRmqU_n9ryLoya?dl=0

I need to return the name "2021_10_03_1236_Audio Guideline" and also the path "/Z_Organisations/Goat_Ltd/Sent/2021_10_03_1236_Audio Guideline".

I own the dropbox where the folders/files I will be linking are stored so I should be able to get the path.

I am presuming I will most likely need to use the official dropbox API to exact the metadata I need from the link so any examples or resources I can read will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to this problem after searching through the Dropbox API documentation https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

I wrote the below code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"url": "' . $dropboxShareableLink . '"}',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . config('app.dropbox.access_token'),
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ]
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response, true);

curl_close($curl);
```

This is using the `get_shared_link_metadata` endpoint to retreive the metadata from the shareable link I passed in the body.

You also need to pass in your dropbox ACCESS_TOKEN in the headers to make sure you have access to the file the link is pointing to.

**NOTE** - You can only access the metadata for folder/files your ACCESS_TOKEN has permission to view. For example you would get an unauthenticated error if you tried to access a file on someone elses dropbox account.